# Linux sed doesn't replace comma

Tags: linux, bash, sed

```
uptime=$(uptime | sed 's/^.*up//;s/:/ hours and /; s/, load/ minutes, load/g')
```

The output is:

```
2 days, 3 hours and 41, load average: 0.04, 0.07, 0.10
```

I want the output to be like this:

```
2 days, 3 hours and 41 minutes, load average: 0.04, 0.07, 0.10
```

How do I do that with `sed` ?

Comment: Try $(uptime | sed 's/^.*up//;s/:/ hours and /;s/, [a-z0-9 ]*,  load/ minutes, load/g'). You are probably missing users logged in.

Comment: What's the output from `uptime` directly? Does adding an extra space between `,` and `load` help?

Comment: @EtanReisner it's already solved

Comment: Yes, but that doesn't answer why yours didn't work. <shrug>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use grouping to capture the hours/mins directly:

```
echo $(uptime | sed 's/^.*up//;s/\([0-9][0-9]*\):\([0-9][0-9]\)*/\1 hours and \2 minutes/')
```

Answer (score 1):

You may need to use 2 `sed` commands:

```
uptime=$(uptime | sed 's/^.*up//;s/:/ hours and /' |sed 's/,\s\+load/ minutes, load/g' )
```

Actually it works with only one, it probably had more than one space:

```
uptime | sed 's/^.*up//;s/:/ hours and /; s/,\s\+load/ minutes, load/g'
```

Comment: Please try that command of yours on your terminal first before posting it here, it doesn't work

Comment: Does not work, gives `6 days, 18 hours and 34,  1 user minutes, load average: 1.39, 1.38, 1.61` correct is `6 days, 18 hours and 34 minutes,  1 user,  load average: 1.36, 1.38, 1.60` .  This is also why I post output of my own command in any answer if its not to long.

Comment: @Jotne I think  OPs  `uptime`  output does not include number of users. It would be useful if he included his uptime output as it may differ.

Comment: What is your output when you run the command at your system?  As I sad, its always good to post it.

Comment: Same as yours, but I need to consider the output on his system not on mine. read his question again, you can't see number of users.

Comment: He like `2 days, 3 hours and 41 minutes, load average: 0.04, 0.07, 0.10`, not what you have posted..

Comment: Exactly consider his output not having number of users, wouldn't it work?

Comment: Ahh see that know.  His output is different. Possible due to different OS.